# Building app from shared folder in Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to build an app from a shared folder in Visual Studio Express 2012.

While building an app from a local folder works just fine, the shared one doesn't. These are the errors thrown when building:

Error   1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app in the layout folder "\VBOXSVR\Repos\App1\App1\bin\Debug\AppX" failed.   App1
Error   2   error 0x80073D55: Recovering DeploymentRequest from file C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\7b7fb2d4-65eb-45d3-808c-3e42a6eacbb4_S-1-5-21-1933965384-392669828-504697624-1001_1.rslc failed.    App1

Instead of using a shared folder in Virtual Box, I've tried to setup a Samba share, which I've mounted as a network drive. Also, I used caspol to make the drive trusted using this technique: http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Network-drives-net-security-and-virtualbox.html

My host OS is Max OSX and my guest OS is Windows 8.

I look forward to hearing your suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's funny how you often find the solution right after you ask the question ;-)

Here's the solution to anyone else interested: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/106132/building-fails-when-build-directory-is-on-a-network-drive